# Using the .nth command within a groupby and keeping columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I would like to use the .nth command to get the 10th largest value in a column within a groupby.  This works but I am left with only the row index and the 10th largest value, losing the columns on which the groupby was performed.  Is there a way to keep the column values used in the group by?  Here is the code I have:

```
test=tmom.groupby(['gameId','playId'],as_index=False)['prox'].nth(10).reset_index()
```

I would like to maintain the columns named 'gameId' and 'playId'.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do that is to just select those columns from the *output* of [`nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nth.html) :

```py
tmom.groupby(['gameId','playId']).nth(10)[['gameId','playId', 'prox']].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Alternatively you could set `['gameId','playId']` as a multi-level index and group by that:

```py
tmom.set_index(['gameId','playId']).groupby(level=[0,1])['prox'].nth(10).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this `df`:

```py
    gameId  playId  prox
0        1       1     1
1        1       1     2
2        1       1     3
3        1       2     4
4        1       2     5
5        1       2     6
6        2       2     7
7        2       2     8
8        2       2     9
9        3       3    10
10       3       3    11
11       3       3    12
```

---

Then:

```py
test = df.loc[df.groupby(["gameId", "playId"])["prox"].nth(1).index]
print(test)
```

Prints:

```
    gameId  playId  prox
1        1       1     2
4        1       2     5
7        2       2     8
10       3       3    11
```